# Deploy php to aws lambda

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I use this guide for deploying code on asw lambda: 
https://cwhite.me/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-aws-lambda/

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var parser = require('http-string-parser');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    // Sets some sane defaults here so that this function doesn't fail when it's not handling a HTTP request from
    });
};
```

This part of code help execute php. But I have error in lambda function:

> Cannot find module 'http-string-parser'

Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html

Comment: Thank you, I added package, deployed and it work!)